# No output from Guitarix with AVLinux with multiple JACK inputs

Tags: pulseaudio, jack

I recently installed AVLinux for low-latency audio recording, which works very well with my chap USB sound card, provided I line in from an external amp, etc. However, since my bass amp line out is incredibly noisy, I have started looking into using Guitarix with either a USB Rocksmith cable or a 1/4"-3.5mm cable.

I have read the AVLinux User Guide (especially re: PulseAudio source/sink), but no matter what I've tried, I don't get any output, even though Guitarix is picking up the guitar (confirmed with the tuner).

[image: Here are my Qjackctl settings]

I'd love to be able to get the Rocksmith cable working as well (same issue - Guitarix can "hear" from the USB but I have no way of hearing any output from Guitarix), but I'd settle for either working.

I feel like I have to be missing something quite obvious. I DO get output from other sources (i.e. Firefox, Audacity).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is too late, but the answer is connect in Qjackctl gx_head_fx (out_0 and out_1) to system (playback_1 and playback_2) and it will work for sure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).